# Drush site install break when a custom commerce feature is enabled, why?

Tags: 7, rules, features, commerce

The D7 site i'm working has a feature that includes two custom product types, amongst other things.  A custom feature gets auto-detected and added as a dependency because it contains a rule on one of the product types.  Another feature added to the site install profile contains the permissions to those types.

After i exported the features and tried to install the site again, it breaks because:

- the product types are do not get created, i expect this log entry to show but does not:
  WD features: Rebuilding feature_name / commerce_product_type
  Which, i'm guessing, is when the types get created from the feature.  That log entry shows on a successful build (see below).
- consequently, the permissions feature causes a fatal error when trying to insert the types permissions into the db, since they don't exist and not defined by a module (from commerce_entity_access_permissions).

The solution for the fix is to manually remove the auto-detected feature with the rules.

I assumed that there's something wrong with that feature but can't think of what.  Has anyone experienced something like that?

Comment: You may want to check your PHP memory. For some reason Commerce installs use a lot of it. If you are running out, your PHP log should tell you.

Comment: no such log entry found... would that also show in the drush output by any chance?

Comment: The location of the PHP error log is given by the configuration variable 'error_log'. If you are running phpinfo, it will display the value in the 'core' section.

Comment: cool, that's where i looked.

Comment: I think i found a small bit of what could be the problem.  When i manually reordered the feature's dependencies, i got a different error.  I moved the commerce_features above the custom one, and the commerce_product_types feature component was recognized.  The new error doesn't break the site install.  More to come when i figure out a better solution then re-ordering the feature's dependencies.

Comment: Still not sure why yet, but reordering dependencies work.  The other error i was seeing was from a custom module that was also added to the feature (auto-detectedly, not that this fact matters though...).  Once i moved it below the rest, the site install was successful.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a problem with Features and how Drush site-install processes.  Basically, `features_include()` is called after each feature is enabled during the site install.  Somehow (but most likely due to the ordering of the dependencies), the `commerce_features` module gets enabled after my custom feature.  As such, `features_include()`, which has already ran and cached its data, skips calling `commerce_features_features_api()`, which is crucial for my custom product types, included in yet another custom feature, to be created.

I opened an issue at http://drupal.org/node/1334438, see for more details and follow-ups.